# I have more columns that I want on my database with my EF Code First model

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm developing an Entity Framework Code First 6.1.2 with .Net Framework 4.5.1 and C#.

I have these two tables:

```
public class CODES
{
    public string CODE { get; set; }
    public int BATCH_ID { get; set; }
    public byte CODE_LEVEL { get; set; }
    public byte COMMISIONING_FLAG { get; set; }

    public virtual AGGREGATION_CHILDS AggregationChild { get; set; }
    public virtual List<AGGREGATION_CHILDS> AggregationChildren { get; set; }
    public virtual BATCHES Batch { get; set; }
}
public class AGGREGATION_CHILDS
{
    public string CODE { get; set; }
    public string CODE_CHILD { get; set; }
    public int POSITION { get; set; }

    public virtual CODES Aggregation { get; set; }
    public virtual CODES Code { get; set; }
}
```

And their Entity Framework maps:

```
class CODESConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<CODES>
{
    public CODESConfiguration()
    {
        HasKey(c => c.CODE);

        Property(c => c.CODE)
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);

        Property(c => c.CODE)
            .HasMaxLength(20);

        Property(c => c.BATCH_ID)
            .IsRequired();

        Property(c => c.CODE_LEVEL)
            .IsRequired();

        Property(c => c.COMMISIONING_FLAG)
            .IsRequired();

        HasRequired(c => c.Batch)
            .WithMany(b => b.Codes)
            .HasForeignKey(c => c.BATCH_ID);
    }
}

class AGGREGATION_CHILDSConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<AGGREGATION_CHILDS>
{
    public AGGREGATION_CHILDSConfiguration()
    {
        HasKey(ag_ch => new { ag_ch.CODE, ag_ch.CODE_CHILD});

        Property(ag_ch => ag_ch.CODE)
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);

        Property(ag_ch => ag_ch.CODE_CHILD)
            .HasMaxLength(20)
            .IsRequired();

        HasRequired(ag_ch => ag_ch.Aggregation)
            .WithOptional(c => c.AggregationChild);

        HasRequired(ag_ch => ag_ch.Code)
            .WithMany(c => c.AggregationChildren)
            .HasForeignKey(ag_ch => ag_ch.CODE_CHILD);
    }
}
```

I want to create these two tables with these relationships:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AGGREGATION_CHILDS]
(
    [CODE] [nvarchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [CODE_CHILD] [nvarchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [POSITION] [int] NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_AGGREGATION_CHILDS] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [CODE] ASC,
        [CODE_CHILD] ASC
    ), 
    CONSTRAINT [FK_AGGREGATION_CHILDS_AGGREGATIONS] FOREIGN KEY ([CODE]) REFERENCES [CODES]([CODE]), 
    CONSTRAINT [FK_AGGREGATION_CHILDS_CODES] FOREIGN KEY ([CODE_CHILD]) REFERENCES [CODES]([CODE])
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CODES]
(
    [CODE] [nvarchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [BATCH_ID] int NOT NULL,
    [CODE_LEVEL] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [COMMISIONING_FLAG] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
     CONSTRAINT [PK_CODES] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [CODE] ASC
    ),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_CODES_BATCHES] FOREIGN KEY ([BATCH_ID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[BATCHES] ([Id])
)
```

But I get this:
[image]

Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

you can use the attribute Notmapped
[EF attribute NotMapped explained](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591583.aspx#NotMapped)

It will not create the field on the DB.

once a foreign key is declared, and index field is used.
You can control the foreign key field name 
[Foreign key attributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591583.aspx#Relationships)
or you have done with  `.HasForeignKey(ag_ch => ag_ch.CODE_CHILD);`

Dont forget you can use the EF power tools to reverse engineer a DB to code first.  SO if you have a simple DB sample. You can generate the code first that maps to that.